# Import json and convert all columns to strings

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to import a (very) large json file (3.3m rows, 1k columns), that has nested multiple nested jsons within it. Some of these nested jsons are double nested. I have found two ways to import the json file into a dataframe, however, I can't get the imported json to be flattened, and converted to strings at he same time.

The codes I am using are:

```py
# 1: Import directly and convert to string
def Data_IMP(path):
    with open(path) as Data:
        Data_IMP = pd.read_json(Data, dtype=str)

    Data_IMP = Data_IMP.replace("nan", "", regex=True)

    return Data_IMP
```

The issue with the above is that it doesn't flatten the json file fully.

```py
# 2: Import json and normalise
def Data_IMP(path):
    with open(path) as Data:
        d = json.load(Data)

    Data_IMP = json_normalize(d)
    return Data_IMP
```

The above script flattens out the json, but lets Python decide on the dtype for each column.

Is there a way to combine these approaches, so that the json file is flattened, and all columns read a strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked, and was able to both import and flatten the jsons, as well as convert all text to strings.

```py
# Function to import data from ARIC json file to dataframe

def Data_IMP(path):
    with open(path) as Data:
        d = json.load(Data)

    Data_IMP = json_normalize(d)
    return Data_IMP
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# Function to cleanse Data file

def Data_Cleanse(Data_IMP):

    Data_Cleanse = Data_IMP.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
    Data_Cleanse = Data_Cleanse.astype(str)

    return Data_Cleanse
```